# Query returns empty result set

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to show the categories (up to level 3) on the menu. This worked so far, but now I added some new sub-categories which are not showing up.

When I dump the result of the **sub-categories query**, it returns an empty result set, but when I execute the same query on the database, it **successfully** returns what its supposed to.

Below is my code:

[Catalog/Controller/Common/Menu](https://gist.github.com/Damian96/e18d4a78acd81f3e07daa7d0ffdffb6d#file-menu-php)

[Catalog/Model/Catalog/Category](https://gist.github.com/Damian96/e18d4a78acd81f3e07daa7d0ffdffb6d#file-category-php)

[Catalog/Theme/Menu](https://gist.github.com/Damian96/e18d4a78acd81f3e07daa7d0ffdffb6d#file-menu-twig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add products to that category, thats why it didnt show up.